# How many clients can use Google sheets service GTL api auth credential?

Tags: ios, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

I have an iOS app that accesses a google drive spreadsheet. To make upgrades to the app without modifying the original sheet, I made a copy of sheet to test the new code. I changed the share permissions on the copy to "anyone with link can edit". I can read the data in the copy, but I cannot change the sheet through the api.

I'm pretty sure the problem is has something to do with credentials and sharing permission.

Do I need a new credential to modify the new sheet? The "version 1" of the app is still in use and it uses the same credential, do I need a new credential for a "version 2" of my app.

What permissions should I use on the google drive sheet?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badly constructed query, I introduced a flaw when I reorganized a class.